# How to check Windows edition in Java?

Tags: java, windows, windowsversion

I want to check Windows edition (Basic or Home or Professional or Business or other) in Java.

How do I do this?

Comment: How would you check it outside Java?

Comment: This article provide some details about the Windows version and edition http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724429(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Vash, even though your article is helpful, the OP wants to get the info from Java (and not C/C++)

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, I realize that. The my intention was to put some light on the way how those data are really stored in system, because the edition is a numeric value not a prepared char set.

Comment: Everybody! Thanks much for your inputs. But, the hunt is still on - I'm looking to find out Windows "EDITION" as stated in OP.

Comment: Not sure if it's a suitable solution for you, but you could run a batch file from java which issues 'systeminfo > whatever.txt' and then you parse the .txt for OS Name which i think contains the edition. Or you call GetProductInfo via JNI.

Comment: @Sannidhi: You can target the right windows version by using the [solution provided by CubaLibre](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/SystemUtils.html#IS_OS_WINDOWS_2000)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always use Java to call the Windows command 'systeminfo' then parse out the result, I can't seem to find a way to do this natively in Java.

```
 import java.io.*;

   public class GetWindowsEditionTest
   {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
         Runtime rt; 
         Process pr; 
         BufferedReader in;
         String line = "";
         String sysInfo = "";
         String edition = "";
         String fullOSName = "";
         final String   SEARCH_TERM = "OS Name:";
         final String[] EDITIONS = { "Basic", "Home", 
                                     "Professional", "Enterprise" };

         try
         {
            rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            pr = rt.exec("SYSTEMINFO");
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

            //add all the lines into a variable
            while((line=in.readLine()) != null)
            {
               if(line.contains(SEARCH_TERM)) //found the OS you are using
               {
                //extract the full os name
                  fullOSName = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(SEARCH_TERM) 
                  + SEARCH_TERM.length(), line.length()-1);
                  break;
               } 
            }

            //extract the edition of windows you are using
            for(String s : EDITIONS)
            {
               if(fullOSName.trim().contains(s))
               {
                  edition = s;
               }
            }

            System.out.println("The edition of Windows you are using is " 
                               + edition); 

         }
            catch(IOException ioe)      
            {   
               System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
            }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Hunter, you are right, not possible through Java directly and thanks for your response. Though I had a solution before your post, I didn't share for some personal reason. Actually, there's a better way:

Comment: Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "CMD /C SYSTEMINFO | FINDSTR /B /C:\"OS Name\"" );
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( process.getInputStream() ) );
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
if( line.indexOf( "Professional" ) > 0 )
 ...

Comment: SYSTEMINFO takes around 3 seconds to finish executing, which is unacceptable if, for example, you need this data on startup of your application, as it would slow down your application by that time.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Apache Commons Library](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/index.html)

The class SystemUtils provides several methods to determine such information.

Comment: +1 @CubaLibre very useful stuff, and it seems to deliver what the OP wants.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is what OP wants because `SystemUtils`' docs mention that they will inturn return the JVM's standard properties `os.name`, `os.version`, and `os.arch`.

Comment: The link is 404.

Answer (score 4):

You can get a lot of information about the System you're running on by asking the JVM about it's System Properties:

```
import java.util.*;
public class SysProperties {
   public static void main(String[] a) {
      Properties sysProps = System.getProperties();
      sysProps.list(System.out);
   }
}
```

more info here: http://www.herongyang.com/Java/System-JVM-and-OS-System-Properties.html

**EDIT:** the property `os.name` seems to be your best bet

Comment: I was thinking about this, but it doesn't return the exact info (windows type) needed by the OP. Maybe he can execute a windows command and read it from that `Process`.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("os.name: " + System.getProperty("os.name"));
    System.out.println("os.version: " + System.getProperty("os.version"));
    System.out.println("os.arch: " + System.getProperty("os.arch"));
}
```

output:

```
os.name: Windows 8.1
os.version: 6.3
os.arch: amd64
```

For more info(the most important system properties):

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Answer (score 1):

The results from `System.getProperty("os.name")` vary between different Java virtual machines (even the Sun/Oracle ones):

A `JRE` will return `Windows 8` for a windows 8 machine. For the same system a `Windows NT (unknown)` is returned when running the same program with a `JDK`.

`System.getProperty("os.version")` seems more reliable on this. For `Windows 7` it returns `6.1` and `6.2` for `Windows 8`.

Comment: Update:  with windows 10 and jre11 apparently os.name is not reliable at all.

Answer (score 0):

Refactored Hunter McMillen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6114981/1762224) to be more efficient and extensible.

```
import java.io.*;

public class WindowsUtils {
    private static final String[] EDITIONS = {
        "Basic", "Home", "Professional", "Enterprise"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("The edition of Windows you are using is: %s%n", getEdition());
    }

    public static String findSysInfo(String term) {
        try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = rt.exec("CMD /C SYSTEMINFO | FINDSTR /B /C:\"" + term + "\"");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            return in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static String getEdition() {
        String osName = findSysInfo("OS Name:");
        if (!osName.isEmpty()) {
            for (String edition : EDITIONS) {
                if (osName.contains(edition)) {
                    return edition;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```